# One Query output execution in another query

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

**Description**

- select maximum reflectance value as max and minimum reflectance value as min where
  wavelength between 650 and 800 and apply formula (max+min)/2+min as radiance
- select the reflectance where wavelength nearer to 700 as r700 and
- select the reflectance where wavelength nearer to 740 as r740

  **Apply Formula**

  **700+(radiance-r700)/(r740-r700)*40**

output value as radtera and i want to display radiance value and radtera value as output

I tried this query, It is showing so many values in radiance and it shows many null values in radtera, but i want only display one radiance value and one radtera value

```
SELECT radiance, (700+(radiance-r700))/((r740-r700)*40) as radtera
FROM (
  SELECT (MAX(reflectance)+MIN(reflectance))/2+MIN(reflectance) as radiance, 
         case when wavelength=700 then reflectance end as r700,
         case when wavelength=740 then reflectance end as r740
  FROM table_name
  WHERE wavelength between 650 and 800
  GROUP BY wavelength,reflectance
) AS SE_23693370
```

If i remove

> *GROUP BY wavelength,reflectance*

this from query, it is showing error

Here is [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/53ded/1).

I checked it, i dont know how it is displaying many values instead of one value show.. Anyone help me to correct mistakes please...

I tried using case statement in  [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/53ded/56).

```
select reip,700+(reip-r45)/(r72-r45)*40 as reipw
from ( 
  select (mx+mn))/2+mn as reip 
from ( 
  select case max(tert) as mx, 
  case min(tert) as mn 
  case when iner=44.5 then tert end as r45, 
  case when iner=72.1 then tert end as r72
  from  table_name
  where iner between 43 and 79)bar
)as SE_23693370
```

It shows *ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias: select reip,700+(reip-r45)/(r72-r45)*40 as reipw from ( select (mx+mn))/2+mn as reip from ( select case max(tert) as mx, case min(tert) as mn case when iner=44.5 then tert end as r45, case when iner=72.1 then tert end as r72 from table_name where iner between 43 and 79) )as SE_23693370*

Comment: Are you trying to get StackOverflow to do your homework for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with the `ROW_NUMBER` function. It is available in [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm), and [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-window.html), amongst others.

```
select radiance, r700, r740,
  (700+(radiance-r700))/((r740-r700)*40) as radtera
from
(select t.reflectance as radiance, 
  t700.wavelength as r700, t740.wavelength as r740
from
  (select max(reflectance) as reflectance
  from table_name) t,
    (SELECT reflectance, wavelength,
      row_number() over (order by abs(wavelength-700)) as rn700
    FROM table_name
    WHERE wavelength between 650 and 800) as t700,
   (SELECT reflectance,wavelength,
      row_number() over (order by abs(wavelength-740)) as rn740
    FROM table_name
    WHERE wavelength between 650 and 800) as t740
  where t700.rn700=1 and t740.rn740=1) as di
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/53ded/54/0)

Comment: Just to complete the picture: window functions (`row_number()`) are available in many more DBMS not just the three you listed. Amongst others: DB2, Teradata, Sybase, Informix and Vertica.